# android correct way to end call in the version 6.0

Tags: android, phone-call

i'm using the next code:

```
public void PhoneCallEnd(Context context) {

        try {
            // Get the boring old TelephonyManager
            TelephonyManager telephonyManager =
                    (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

            // Get the getITelephony() method
            Class classTelephony = Class.forName(telephonyManager.getClass().getName());
            Method methodGetITelephony = classTelephony.getDeclaredMethod("getITelephony");

            // Ignore that the method is supposed to be private
            methodGetITelephony.setAccessible(true);

            // Invoke getITelephony() to get the ITelephony interface
            Object telephonyInterface = methodGetITelephony.invoke(telephonyManager);

            // Get the endCall method from ITelephony
            Class telephonyInterfaceClass = Class.forName(telephonyInterface.getClass().getName());


            Method methodEndCall = telephonyInterfaceClass.getDeclaredMethod("endCall");

            // Invoke endCall()
            methodEndCall.invoke(telephonyInterface);

        } catch (Exception ex) { // Many things can go wrong with reflection calls

            String error=ex.toString();
            Toast.makeText(context, "error: "+ error , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            txtHome.setText("error: "+ error);//cambio el contenido del TextView


        }

    }
```

The problem is that i get the next error "java.lang.reflect.invocationTargetException"

the aplication crash in the line "methodEndCall.invoke(telephonyInterface);"

Could you tell me about the correct way to refuse the current call?

Comment: can you show your stacktrace?

Comment: how can i see its?

Comment: copy the whole  error log for java.lang.reflect.invocationTargetException

Comment: the error is java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10123 nor current process has android.permission.CALL_PHONE.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define permissions in your manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

For sdk version greater than  or equal to 23 you need run time permissions. In your activity you can get runtime permissions like this

```
public static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE = 101;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

  if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
        Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
        Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
            Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)) {
        // Show an explanation for read phone state
    } else 
     if(ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
            Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)){
        // Show an explanation for call phone
    }else {

        // No explanation needed

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE,Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE},
                MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE);
        // result of the request.
    }
  }else{
       //permission already available
       //do the required task here
  }
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                   String permissions[], int[] 
grantResults) {
  switch (requestCode) {
    case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_READ_PHONE_STATE: {
        // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
        if (grantResults.length > 0
                && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            // permission granted
            // do the required task here

        } else {
            // permission denied
        }
        return;
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: See the update answer for run time permissions for Marshmallow and above

Comment: See the updated answer for both permissions in run time

Answer (score 0):

@shiriyas

I fixed the error.

Thanks for helping me.

The problem was that i was checking for perms in the onCreate method.

When i checked for perms in the PhoneCallEnd method the problem was resolved

Sorry but it's my first app and as you can see i did not use very well the tools  =(